# Customizing font used by algorithmicx

Tags: fonts, xetex, algorithms

I am using `algorithmicx` to typeset my algorithms in XeTeX. Using `fontspec`, I set the default font to be Linux Libertine with historical ligatures (e.g., `ct`, `st`). Unfortunately, this is also the font used by `algorithmicx` to typeset my algorithms and historical ligatures look very much out of place there.

This is likely a newbie question, but is there any way to customize the font used within the `algorithmic` environment without specifying the custom font at the beginning of each such environment?

A simple solution is to define a new environment

```
\newenvironment{halgorithmic}
   { \begin{algorithmic}\algofont }
   { \end{algorithmic} }
```

and use `halgorithmic` instead of `algorithmic`. Is there a cleaner method that comes to mind?

Comment: Not much else, unless you want to include it in the definition of `algorithmic`. This would allow you to use leave your code unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is clean and clear, and I would maybe only prefer not to enclose everything in two groups, and to tweak the environment directly instead:

```
\let\algorithmicOLD\algorithmic
\def\algorithmic{\algorithmicOLD\algofont}
```

Now you can use `\begin{algorithmic}` directly. The advantage is that it can't happen to you that you'd use the wrong one, getting the wrong fonts.

Comment: Ah, good; I saw this used but thought it only applied to commands, line \textbf{}, but didn't realize \let applies to environments as well.